# Relation between resistance, capacitance and resistivity

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance, capacitance

I recently learnt that for a resistive medium, $RC = ρε$ where $R$ is the medium's resistance, $C$ is the capacitance, and $\rho$ is the resistivity. Now, I am able to prove that this is true in the case of a parallel plate capacitor with a partially conductive dielectric inside as $$R = \frac{\rho d}{A}$$ and
$$C = \frac{εA}{d}$$

However, I have been made aware that this relation holds for all geometries of resistive media. My question is, why is this true, i.e., what is the proof behind this equation? Also, when is it valid, and when is it not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modelling a capacitor with dielectric resistance as a circuit element](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/315337/modelling-a-capacitor-with-dielectric-resistance-as-a-circuit-element)

Comment: @Chemomechanics not really... i felt like the linked question deals with the specific case of parallel plates, which I mentioned I know. My main problem is with the more general argument

Comment: Makes sense; I'll retract my vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this claim?

Comment: @Puk my physics teacher told me this and gave many instances where it's working, I couldn't find it in any textbook but have seen problems online where it's used to get the correct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the analogy between electrostatic in a dielectric medium and stationary current behavior in a resistive medium, both being isotropic and piece-wise homogeneous is that they follow the same mathematical partial differential equations and boundary conditions.

For electrostatics you can start with $\mathbf D = \epsilon \mathbf E$ and
$$\nabla \times \mathbf E = 0\tag{1a},$$ $$\nabla \cdot \mathbf D= \nabla \cdot \epsilon \mathbf E = \rho \tag{1b}$$
from which you get for $\mathbf E = - \nabla \phi$ and the differential equation for $\phi$ as $\nabla \cdot (\epsilon \nabla \phi) = -\rho.$ In a dielectric medium without free charges, $\rho=0$, this reduces to:
$$\nabla \cdot (\epsilon \nabla \phi) = 0. \tag{2}$$

For a stationary current distribution in a conductive medium, $\tfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=0$ with $\mathbf J = \sigma \mathbf E$:
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf J = 0 \tag{3}$$ and then
$$\nabla \cdot \sigma \mathbf E = 0 \tag{4}$$
but since for stationary current $\tfrac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t}=0$, you again have (1a) and with $\mathbf E = - \nabla \psi$ you can write:$\nabla \cdot \sigma \nabla \psi = 0$ that in a homogeneous medium becomes
$$\nabla \cdot (\sigma \nabla \psi) = 0 \tag{5}$$

Apparently the two potentials, the electrostatic $\phi$ and the stationary current $\psi$ satisfy the same partial differential equation if we identify the permittivity $\epsilon$ in (2) with the conductivity $\sigma$ in (5).

Boundary conditions are also similar. For electrostatics, $\phi$ is satisfying (2) and at metal boundaries $\phi = \text{constant}$ with the normal component of $\mathbf D=\epsilon \mathbf E$ being continuous. In the case of stationary current, at the electrode the current $\mathbf J = \sigma \mathbf E$ is perpendicular to the metal, hence $\psi= \text{constant}$, while at interfaces the normal component of $\mathbf J=\sigma \mathbf E$ is continuous.

Comment: Could you please explain how this connects resistance and capacitance? I don't understand it...

Comment: In the equations of electrostatics there is material constant called permittivity $\epsilon$ to describe the relationship between flux density $D$ and electric field intensity $E$ : $D=\epsilon E$. In the equations for stationary currents there is another material constant called conductance $\sigma$ to describe the relationship between current density $J$ and electric field intensity $E$: $J=\sigma E$. The differential equations and boundary conditions are the same type, the only difference between them is the appearance of the material constants $\epsilon$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: Oh so these expressions are symmetrical and hence E can be replaced?

Comment: I would not call it "symmetrical" rather they are the *same* equations for the electric potentials $\phi$ and $\psi$, and  thus for their gradient the electric field $E$. What I wrote is not really the full answer, by the time I finished it I forgot the original question...  anyhow, you get the full picture when you take it together with @JerroldFranklin's answer above, who actually wrote down what I forgot to add, specifically how from the equality of the equations and from $\phi=\psi$ to $E$ fields come about $RC=\tfrac{\epsilon}{\sigma}$.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, thanks! Also, from the previous answer by @JerroldFranklin, could you say if it's valid to use a closed integral for I? I feel like that would only work if there are rest charges present as the net result would or else = 0. I may be wrong though as I'm kind of new to this

Comment: Yes, to calculate the total current leaving the electrode you need to calculate a closed surface integral completely enclosing the electrode and this is important for the complete analogy between $D$ and $J$. For $\oint D$ around an electrode of *capacitor* is actually the total charge enclosed within the surface and is sitting on the electrode, and is the charge the capacitor holds, this Gauss's law.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. One more thing - so would it be invalid if the capacitors are uncharged?

Comment: it would still be valid but the integral would be 0, because then $D=0$ and $E=0$, too.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much!

Comment: This may be a bit off-topic, but can you mention in what kinds of cases this relation doesn't work?

Comment: what relation you mean?

Comment: The one I had mentioned in the question - RC = $\rho$ $\epsilon$

Comment: I'm struggling to think of a case where this proof would fail and the relation wouldn't hold. Or is it that it always works?

Comment: I think the two answers together *prove* that $RC=\epsilon/\sigma$ always works within the confines of electrostatics, stationary currents, linear piece-wise homogeneous and isotropic media and ideal conducting surfaces as electrodes.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: The only thing you have to be careful of is that $\sigma=0$ (vacuum) does NOT correspond to  $\epsilon=\epsilon_0$ (vacuum), there is no $\epsilon=0$ in nature, and unless $\sigma >0$ everywhere there will be an error when replacing $\sigma$ with $\epsilon$. The error will manifest itself in the vacuum stray field on the sides of the capacitor; there is no stray current where $\sigma = 0$, the stray current is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The effective resistance between two electrodes is given by the ratio of integrals
\begin{equation}
R= \frac{V}{I} = \left|\frac{\int\bf E\cdot dr}{\oint\bf j\cdot dA}\right|
 = \left|\frac{\int\bf E\cdot dr}{\sigma\oint\bf E\cdot dA}\right|. . 
\end{equation}
The capacitance of the two electrodes is given the ratio $Q/V$, where $Q$ is the magnitude of the charge on each electrode given, from Gauss's law by
\begin{equation}
Q =\left|\epsilon\oint\bf E\cdot dA\right|.
\end{equation}
This gives the capacitance as the ratio of integrals
\begin{equation}
C=  \frac{Q}{V} =\left|\frac{\epsilon\oint\bf E\cdot dA}{\int\bf E\cdot dr}\right|. 
\end{equation}
The integrals cancel in the product $RC$, so
\begin{equation}
RC = \frac{\epsilon}{\sigma}
\end{equation}

Comment: Is it valid to say $I$ is the closed integral of j $\cdot$ dA? I may be wrong but that would only work if there are rest charges present in our assumed Gaussian surface or else the integral would simply become 0... Again, I may be wrong as I'm new to this, so feel free to let me know if I am

Comment: I think I is the integral of j $\cdot$ dA at an open surface, although I'm not sure what happens in a closed surface. But in an open surface, it isn't as far as I know, valid to say it's equal to $\frac{Q}{\epsilon}$

Comment: $\oint\bf j\cdot dA$ is the rate at which charge is leaving a closed surface about one of the electrodes. That is a definition of the current passing through the closed surface.   It is not a Gaussian surface.  I don't know what follows your ...

Comment: Yeah I am aware of that but I was curious about the case of uncharged electrodes. My bad if I framed my question incorrectly